# PCR test still required to travel to Istanbul?

Tags: covid-19, turkey

I will travel to Istanbul on April 29th.

Is PCR test still required? I have read one of the Turkey visa selling websites that a PCR test is required. The information from Turkish airlines is different, for who has received two doses of vaccin, there is no need for PCR test before departure. Very confusing.

The same thing for the Entry Form which is still required on this website, but not required for Turkish Airline. Could anyone please clarify?

Thank you very much in advance for answering my questions.

Best regards,
Lisa

Comment: As the website you mentioned is a commercial site selling visa (and not an official one) I am going to edit it out and you can ignore it for the official information of the government.

Comment: I have added the tag [tag:covid-19] to your question, because I assume you are referring to PCR tests for SARS-CoV-2 and not for any other virus.

Answer (score 2):

The Turkish government doesn't seem to have any official sites for this, but other countries have government agencies that report it as such (as of Apr 18, 2022)

[US State Dept - Turkish Embassy](https://tr.usembassy.gov/covid-19-information-2/)

> Passengers, regardless of their nationality, over the age of 18 who have not been vaccinated or with no record of Covid-19 (recovery) are required to submit PCR tests with a negative result, performed at most 48 hours before their domestic flight, as of September 6, 2021. PCR tests are not required in domestic flights for those who are vaccinated and flight is at least 14 days after the second dose or for those who are in the immunity period after a Covid19 infection.

[Canada](https://travel.gc.ca/destinations/turkey)

> In an attempt to limit the spread of COVID-19, most governments have implemented preventative measures and restrictions.
>
> These could include:
>
> - curfews, movement restrictions, or lockdowns
> - the obligation to wear a face-covering, a surgical or respirator mask in some circumstances
> - the obligation to present proof of vaccination or a COVID-19 test result to access public and private services and spaces, including transportation, restaurants and cultural sites
>
> Foreign authorities might not recognize or accept proof of vaccination issued by Canadian provinces and territories. You may need to obtain a translation, a notarization, an authentication, or the legalization of the document.

I have not found another major country governmental website that disagrees with either of these previous ones.

The answer seems to be that, yes, you will be required to have official vaccination papers OR a negative PCR test. These regulations are subject to change.

Comment: The Turkish Airlines site is up to date and close to authoritative: https://www.turkishairlines.com/en-us/announcements/coronavirus-outbreak/turkey-travel-rules/

Comment: Neither of the citations in this answer are relevant. The US one is about domestic flights and the Canada one is generic “maybe” wording. Further down on the US page, it says that “fully vaccinated” passengers do not need a test unless they come from a few listed countries. I have not researched whether this information is accurate and up to date.